# Internal error when I add htaccess in wampserver localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, module

When i add the htaccess to my wampserver I am receiving internal error.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is the code I added to htaccess

Comment: An "internal error", so a http status 500, is just what the http server tells requesting clients. You as the owner of the server need further information. You can get that from the error log file the http server writes. That is where you can read what the specific issue is the server stumbled upon.

Comment: It might be that you did not load the rewriting module ...

Comment: Check the apache log for details

Comment: I resolved by using xampp than wampserver